# Do something While view receives gestures

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I want to change a view `backgroundColor` while it is receiving `UILongPressGesture`, how can I do it properly? With the code below everything freezes forever, even if I lift my finger it won't unfreeze.

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
 while ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [self.Row2View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.2]];
    }
}
```

**EDIT** What I need is: While `UILongPressGesture` change color , When finger lifts the screen change color back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use while! when enter the loop, the condition will always be true!

first,change while to **if**. then according to apple document:

> Long-press gestures are continuous. The gesture begins (`UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`) when the number of allowable fingers (`numberOfTouchesRequired`) have been pressed for the specified period (`minimumPressDuration`) and the touches do not move beyond the allowable range of movement (`allowableMovement`). The gesture recognizer transitions to the **Change state** whenever a finger moves, and it ends (`UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`) when any of the fingers are lifted.

I think you should use **Began State**(when gesture got recognized) or **Ended State**(when a recognized gesture release up). if you don't want to call method continuously when touch moves.

```
if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    [self.Row2View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.2]];
}
```

--- **EDIT** ---

according to you description, you want to change color when touch and restore when release. so it will be:

```
if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    Row2ViewOriginColor = self.Row2View.backgroundColor; // you can declare this var in the class.
    [self.Row2View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.2]];
}
else if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
         [gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
    [self.Row2View setBackgroundColor: Row2ViewOriginColor];
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it wont change `BackgroundColor` to the "before" state when finger lifts the screen. I can make it work by setting desired color before `if` and make  `if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorBefore]];
}` but I need to make it work without setting  `BackgroundColor` before if.

Comment: So to make it simple: I need to `set` different `BackgroundColor` when there is `UILongPressGesture` on a view, and after finger lifts the screen (it is `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`) return my color back as it was before `UILongPressGesture`. But I need to make it without actually setting `BackgroundColor` to initial state like `[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor returnColorBeforeUILongPressGestureChangedIt]]`.

Comment: You have to set the color back manually, you can set the long press color at began, and recover at ended. you may need a var to save the previous color.

Comment: if you previous color is a const value, you can write it literally. but if it's a variable value, it must be saved somewhere. since set new value overwrite old value and old value get lost.

Answer (score 2):

Because the "while" block will never break! Just change the "while"  block to "if"!

Answer (score 0):

Add a property

```
@property (copy) UIColor *initialBackgroundColor;
```

Handle Long Press

```
- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        self.initialBackgroundColor = self.Row2View.backgroundColor;
        [self.Row2View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.2]];
    }
    else if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ||
             [gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
             [gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
    {
        [self.Row2View setBackgroundColor:self.initialBackgroundColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is the same code as @SolaWing wrote above.